# asp: Image cannot display from directory path

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I cannot display my picture from folder when I replace the image1.ImageUrl = "D:\SavedImages\profile.jpg"

I save the path name into my database and then I redirect the path name into a text so that when it loads, the image1.ImageUrl = textBox1.Text

I tried to preview the image that I upload first in my

after that i saved the directory in my database called "pathname"

then when saved, the page reload and should display image from the filepath that i used to saved the image. but its not working.

if anything I really appreciate you guys help.

thank you.

I tried, Almost everything haha

Here is my upload button

```
 Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
        If FileUpload1.HasFile Then


            Try


                ' If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("C:\Users\nor.iman\Desktop\Pictures\") Then
                ' My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory("C:\Users\nor.iman\Desktop\Pictures\")
                'End If

                Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("/Image/" + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)


                FileUpload1.SaveAs(path)

                Image1.ImageUrl = "/Image/" + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName

                TextBox1.Text = Server.MapPath("/Image/" + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
                TextBox2.Text = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName


            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("ERROR")
            End Try
        Else
            MsgBox("You have not specified a file")
        End If

    End Sub
```

Here is my PageLoad

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load



        If Not IsPostBack Then


            Dim key1 = Request.QueryString("id")
            Dim query As String = "SELECT  * From Users  U left Join Countries C ON (U.countryId = C.countryId) WHERE userName='" & key1 & "'"

            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, dbConn)
            Dim id As String = txtuserName.Text

            dbConn.Open()
            Dim myreader As SqlDataReader
            myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            myreader.Read()
            If myreader.HasRows Then
                txtuserName.Text = myreader.Item("userName").ToString()
                txtAddress.Text = myreader.Item("userAddress").ToString()
                DropDownCountry.SelectedValue = myreader.Item("Country").ToString()
                txtfname.Text = myreader.Item("firstName").ToString()
                txtlname.Text = myreader.Item("lastName").ToString()
                txtPassword.Text = myreader.Item("userPassword").ToString()
                txtConfirm.Text = myreader.Item("userPassword").ToString()
                txtEmail.Text = myreader.Item("userEmail").ToString()
                SecurityList.SelectedValue = myreader.Item("userSecurity").ToString()
                txtAnswer.Text = myreader.Item("userAnswer").ToString()
                txtId.Text = myreader.Item("userId").ToString()
                TextBox1.Text = myreader.Item("filepath").ToString()
                TextBox2.Text = myreader.Item("imageName").ToString()


                Image1.ImageUrl = "/Image/" + TextBox2.Text


            End If
            dbConn.Close()

        End If


    End Sub
```

Comment: `MsgBox` is for desktop programming, if you have any error, you will never see it

Comment: also is logical to not been able to see images from `D:\SavedImages\` - place them in a subdirectory, inside the web directory of your site

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying.  I am programming for website using visual studio. and I've also fixed the problem to display.

Comment: I've edited the question and posted the correct  code inside one.

Answer (score 0):

Iman,

Try:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("/Image/" + TextBox2.Text)
```

Comment: I tried it like this, but it seems that it still cannot retrieve the image.

Comment: Image1.ImageUrl = "/Image/" + TextBox2.Text seems that when I just put the name of the image into "TextBox2.Text" it works.